# Cytoscape preset layout - question referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841293/cytoscape-js-preset-layout-documentation

Tags: position, cytoscape.js, preset

I am using localStorage to store euler layout, circle layout and grid layout which can be chosen users in frontend. I am able to store the data of the different layouts chosen by the users but NOT able to retrieve them properly:

Snippet of the variable:

```
const key_1 = this.graph_layout_type
```

Snippet to store the data :

```
localStorage.setItem(key_1, JSON.stringify(this.cy.json()))
```

Snippet to retrieve the data:

```
if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key_1)){
this.cy.elements().remove();
this.cy.json({ elements: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key_1)).elements}).layout({
name: 'preset',
positions: undefined,// map of (node id) => (position obj); or function(node){ return somPos; }
zoom: undefined, // the zoom level to set (prob want fit = false if set)
pan: undefined, // the pan level to set (prob want fit = false if set)
fit: true, // whether to fit to viewport
padding: 30, // padding on fit
animate: false, // whether to transition the node positions
animationDuration: 500, // duration of animation in ms if enabled
animationEasing: undefined, // easing of animation if enabled
ready: undefined, // callback on layoutready
stop: undefined // callback on layoutstop
}).run();
}
```

Anyone can help on what should I put in the "position" of the preset-layout option?

Resources I am referring to:

[Cytoscape.js Preset Layout Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841293/cytoscape-js-preset-layout-documentation)

[How to save and restore layout of compound nodes using cytoscape.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62228770/how-to-save-and-restore-layout-of-compound-nodes-using-cytoscape-js)

[Cytoscape.js: precompute graph layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075914/cytoscape-js-precompute-graph-layout)

[CYTOSCAPE JS dijkstra algorithm with preset layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154394/cytoscape-js-dijkstra-algorithm-with-preset-layout)

[Cytoscape layout to use node attributes as coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62094947/cytoscape-layout-to-use-node-attributes-as-coordinates)

[Is it possible to store Cytoscape.js layout data directly to a file format in app/web server and re-launch the same layout to minimize re-computation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66701880/is-it-possible-to-store-cytoscape-js-layout-data-directly-to-a-file-format-in-ap/66718769#66718769)

Comment: Just don't call any layout. Just load the elements. Delete `.layout({...}).run();`

Comment: Able to launch the items with the same position, the number of edges are duplicated. Have you encounter this issue before?

Comment: `this.cy.elements().remove();` should delete all the edges. It shouldn't happen. Are you sure somehow you are not adding more edges? Edges should also have an id. There can be multiple edges between 2 nodes. So to distinguish edges, Cytoscape needs edge ids.

Comment: There is a slider control functions where users can increase and decrease the number of nodes appearing in FE. Before I implemented the setItem and getItem, it is working perfectly fine. But, after implementing setItem and getItem, the edges will get duplicated when number of nodes is decreased and local storage is saving that.

Comment: Ok. It seems like you are adding the same edges again and again

Comment: Thank you for your help! Noted with the points.

Comment: This issue is resolve by pulling the data from the backend again after I did this.cy.elements().remove()